# Switch statement doesn't work in my C program?

Tags: c, switch-statement

As In title I have a Problem with my switch statement. The problem is that it doesn't go into the cases after user inputs a char, it just displays the default case. Here is my code:(The function name is ask_for_command(int *p, int num_mov))

```
char choice = ' ';
printf("\nNEW MOVEMENT : Enter a valid command by keyword :\nValid commands : a d w x");
choice = getchar();
printf("\n");
switch (choice)
{
    case 'a':
        p--;
        num_mov++;
        break;

    case 'd':
        p++;
        num_mov ++;
        break;

    default:
        printf("Wrong Command, a d w x only.\n");
        break;

}
```

And here is where im calling the function :

```
while (!is_pal(a))
{
    if (!is_pal(a))
    {
        print_status(a, p, num_mov);
        printf("\n");
        ask_for_command(p, num_mov);
    }
```

So how to fix up my switch statement so it does its job ?

Comment: Add `printf("%c",choice)` after taking the input. What does it show?

Comment: Or `"%d\n"` for that matter, so you see the ASCII code, not the printable char (which might be non-obvious for space and control characters).

Comment: Add another call to `getchar()` right after the first call. It's likely that the newline is (that you enter along with a char input) causing the issue.

Comment: `getchar()` returns an integer value. Change the type of `choice` to `int` and check for EOF.

Comment: from what i was able to debug my code goes into the proper switch case but then on the while loop it goes into it again and exits with default case prompting for input. What should I do to avoid it the deafult case ?

Comment: @ott: Although in general a a good idea, how would this help in the OP's particular problem?

Comment: @Blue Moon your answer fixed my problem, Thank you (:

Comment: There is another problem: `p` and `num_mov` are passed by value by the calling function, they are not modified by the `ask_for_command` function.  The `ask_for_command` modifies its arguments, not the local variables of the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling this in a loop of some sort; you should be aware that once a command is typed an the user hits return, there are *two* characters in `stdin`: the typed char and a newline character. So the next time it's called, `getchar()` reads the newline and since it doesn't match any of your `switch` cases, it goes to `default`.

Also note that, as pointed by chqrlie in the comments below, you're passing integer arguments by value to your function, inside which they're new, local variables and changing them will not do what you want.

You could fix all this like so:

```
printf("\nNEW MOVEMENT : Enter a valid command by keyword :\nValid commands : a d w x");
char choice;
if (scanf(" %c", &choice) == EOF)
{
    // act accordingly
}
printf("\n");
switch (choice)
{
    case 'a':
        *p--;
        *num_mov++;
        break;

    case 'd':
        *p++;
        *num_mov ++;
        break;

    default:
        printf("Wrong Command, a d w x only.\n");
        break;

}
```

And pass the arguments as pointers: `ask_for_command(&p, &num_mov);`.

Note the space in front if `" %c"`; this instructs `scanf` to ignore whitespace characters, i.e. read `stdin` until it encounters a non-whitespace character, then read that and put it in `choice`.

Comment: There is another problem: `p` and `num_mov` are passed by value by the calling function, they are not modified by the `ask_for_command` function.  The `ask_for_command` modifies its arguments, not the local variables of the caller.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and answers. I'm fairly new to C language so I'm still learning. Thank you again